# Calculated column from two MONEY data type values not displaying correctly in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

The dollar amount is a calculated column value based on two MONEY datatype values.  I need some help to know how to make the 60000.00 display like the 10000.00 value is displayed in my SSRS report.  I am confused as to why the 10000.00 value displays correctly but the 60000.00 does not from the same result set.  I am using VS 2015.

Any suggestions/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is my SQL Server 2016 query result:

[image]

In my SSRS report the 60000.00 value is displaying as 0.00:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your textbox **Textbox Properties > Number > Currency** (or just number, if its not money) and chose your displayed format style. Then go into your textbox expression and add:

```
=CDbl(Fields!YourNumberField.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help.  That appears to have worked.  I just didn't understand why the 10000.00 value would display properly in the report but NOT the 60000.00 value.  Thanks again.